# Storyboard outlet's weak references retention unclear behavior

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, interface-builder, iboutlet

Objects added to an interface builder scene created from an "Object" template can have referencing outlets on the view controller marked both as weak and strong. We have recently observed a behavior where the outlet to an "Object" marked as weak would retain its value after the view controller creation and past the viewDidLoad() and viewDidAppear(_:) calls. This means only one thing: the object is being retained because it's strongly referenced elsewhere.

Who references the "Object" object? How to obtain a reference to it without an @IBOutlet?

Comment: What do you mean by "Object" template? Also, what do you expect the desired behavior to be when you said, "We have recently observed a behavior where the outlet to an "Object" marked as weak would retain".

Comment: Here's a picture from another post on semi-similar topic. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbPUh.png
The behavior we expected is to be instantly released upon initialization, since there are no strong references.

Comment: I see conflicting answers online. I'm currently trying to replicate your situation and figure out who hold that reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried to replicate what you're asking, by adding the `NSObject` "Object", in Interface Builder. (Based on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbPUh.png) image you referenced in your comment)

I ran the project, **without adding any code to the ViewController file**.

And to my surprise, the "Object" did instantiate.

Here, is the implementation of the NSObject subclass I used to test.

```
class TestObj: NSObject {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("TestObj: init called")
    }

    deinit {
        print("TestObj: deinit called")
    }
}
```

Next, I used the Memory Graph Debugger to find out who's holding what. Here's a screenshot of the debugger.

[image: Memory Graph Debugger Screenshot]

The `SettingsTableViewController` is what I attached the "Object" to, in Interface Builder.

Keep in mind that there is no code in `SettingsTableViewController` referring to the "Object".

As you can see, there's a private property on `UIViewController`, called `_topLevelObjectsToKeepAliveFromStoryboard` which is holding a strong reference to the "Object".

This reference will only clear out, when the view controller leaves the heap.

And answering your second question, since the `_topLevelObjectsToKeepAliveFromStoryboard` is a private property, you will not be able to access it from within your `UIViewController` subclass.

Here, you will have to use an `IBOutlet` to get a reference to that "Object". Also, there is a lot of debate, on weather an `IBOutlet` should be `weak` or `strong`, but that is up to you.

Comment: Your effort is priceless and this answer is a mastapeece.

Comment: This indeed seems to be the case. This renders setting `@IBOutlet` references to `nil` useless, since setting `nil` doesn't actually make the object go away. Such a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

When you drag a `Button` from the `object library` onto your `Storyboard's` scene, when that scene is instantiated at runtime, the `object` associated for that button will be created. in order to interact with  that object , you just hold `weak` reference to that object in your ViewController.

[image]

Comment: You statement is valid, but not sufficient for the case presented in the question. Thank you very much.